# Binary optimization problem

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, binary-programming

I am facing the following problem:

Let ***P*** be a fixed ***m x n*** finite matrix and ***D*** be a matrix of ones and zeros with the same dimensionality as ***P*** plus the following constraints:

- sum of row entries <= ***c1*** (for each row)
- sum of column entries <= ***c2*** (for each column)
- maximally ***c3*** rows may contain ones

  *(* ***c1***, ***c2*** *and* ***c3*** *are some fixed natural numbers)*

The task is to find such D matrix (under those constraints), so that the
**sum of entries of (P.*D)** is maximized.

Note that by ".*" I mean *entry-by-entry* product.

If you have any study material recommendations or a way to approach it, I will be happy for any suggestions. 
Thank you.

Comment: Your feasible set isn't convex because the entries of D are constrained to 0-1.  You can relax this constraint to get an LP that is easy to solve.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in one shot if you have an integer linear programming engine. Let's define a vector variable $q\in\{0,1\}^m$. We'll set this up so that all of the elements of row $i$ of $D$ must be zero if $q_i=0$. Then we have
\begin{array}{lll}
\text{maximize}   & \sum_{ij} P_{ij} D_{ij} \\
\text{subject to} & D_{ij} \leq q_i & i=1,2,\dots, m, ~j=1,2,\dots n \\
                  & \sum_j D_{ij} \leq c_1 & i=1,2,\dots, m \\
                  & \sum_i D_{ij} \leq c_2 & j=1,2,\dots, n \\
                  & \sum_i q_i \leq c_3 \\
                  & D\in\{0,1\}^{m\times n} \\ & q\in\{0,1\}^m
\end{array}

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplicity, let $c_3 = m$. We then have the following **binary program**

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \operatorname{tr} (P^T D)\\ \text{subject to} & D 1_n \leq c_1 \, 1_n\\ & D^T 1_m \leq c_2 \, 1_m\\ & D \in \{0,1\}^{m \times n}\end{array}$$

Relaxing the binary constraint, we have the following **linear program**

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \operatorname{tr} (P^T D)\\ \text{subject to} & D 1_n \leq c_1 \, 1_n\\ & D^T 1_m \leq c_2 \, 1_m\\ & D \in [0,1]^{m \times n}\end{array}$$

Suppose that the optimal solution of the LP is $D^*$. We then use a rounding scheme

$$\rho_{\gamma} (x) := \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x \geq \gamma\\ 0 & \text{if } x < \gamma\end{cases}$$

in order to obtain a matrix $\rho_{\gamma} (D^*) \in \{0,1\}^{m \times n}$. We then adjust the threshold $\gamma \in [0,1]$ in an attempt to satisfy the constraint that at most $c_3$ rows contain ones, while still satisfying the two inequality constraints on the sum of the entries on each row and column.

Comment: Why not assume the use of an MILP solver?

Comment: @MichaelGrant I don't have a MILP solver, so I don't have much experience modeling problems as MILP problems. Your answer is much better than mine. I will delete mine.

Comment: Oh don't delete it! It's good to have alternatives.